# How to check CSRF token is valid or not after custom form submit in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am working on CodeIgniter custom form, In this form, I have used CSRF token after form submit I want to check in controller after form submit if CSRF token is valid or not, can anyone please help me for this issue?

> PHP Form code

```
<form role="form" data-parsley-validate="" novalidate="" class="mb-lg" action="?c=
    <?php echo isset($controller) ? $controller : "welcome"; ?>&m=login" method="post">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input name="email" id="exampleInputEmail1" type="email" placeholder="Enter email" autocomplete="off" required class="form-control">
        <span class="fa fa-envelope form-control-feedback text-muted"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input name="password" id="exampleInputPassword1" type="password" placeholder="Password" required class="form-control">
        <span class="fa fa-lock form-control-feedback text-muted"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <a href="?c=<?php echo isset($controller) ? $controller : "welcome"; ?>&m=resetpassword" class="text-muted">Forgot your password?</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
    $csrf = array(
        'name' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),
        'hash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
    );
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $csrf['name'];?>" value="<?php echo $csrf['hash'];?>" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary mt-lg">Login</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeIgniter does this for you automatically. If it is not valid it will do a `show_error` with `show_error('The action you have requested is not allowed.', 403);`

Relevant functions can be found in the `/system/core/security` class, functions: `csrf_verify()` and `csrf_show_error()` (if invalid).

---

If you have understood by now, if you have csrf enabled in the config and you do not have the appropriate csrf hidden field or use `form_open` (which adds the field for you) then when you post the request it will fail with the above message. The same goes for AJAX requests - to automate this for ajax requests you can add this to the top of you page wherever there is an ajax request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        token["<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>"] = "<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>";
        jQuery.ajaxSetup({data: token, type: "POST"});
</script>
```

Comment: csrf values will not be in $_POST. The system core csrf_verify() unsets the csrf values in $_POST

Comment: @vicky this is a ajaxSetup function that has nothing to do with server side things like get or post. this simply says that on a ajax request for post, send the token as a variable.